# Grid layout problems: different sizes when rendering on Mac and Windows

Tags: bugs, grid-layouts

From the documentation for `ItemSize`:

> {w,h} make all items the specified width and height

and

> In Grid, w is measured in ems, and h in line heights.

This implies that a specification `ItemSize->{4,2}` means the item is 4ems wide and 2 line heights high, which in turn suggests that the item size in pixels will be `CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]*4` wide and `CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]*high`. Therefore to make grids that render to a fixed number of pixels across various platforms you presumably should do (for an item of pixel dimension w,h = 100,20):

```
ItemSize:>{100/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"],20/CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]}
```

**If this is not correct stop reading now and let me know!**

The problem I have is that from Mac to Windows I am unable to get the same dimensions:

```
img1 = Rasterize[Grid[RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10, 8}],
   Alignment -> {Center, Center},
   Background -> None,
   BaseStyle -> 
    Directive[FontFamily :> CurrentValue["PanelFontFamily"], 
     FontSize :> CurrentValue["PanelFontSize"], 
     RGBColor[0, 0, 0.25]],
   Frame -> All,
   FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.5], GrayLevel[0.7]],
   ItemSize :> {{80, 260, {130}}/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"], 
     22/CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]},
   Spacings -> {0, 0}]]
```

[image]

```
ImageDimensions[img1]
```

Mma 8.0.4 on Mac 10.6.8

```
(* {751, 224} *)
```

Mma 8.0.4 on on Windows 7

```
(* {983, 274} *)
```

And when we check the em widths and line heights on both systems:

Mma 8.0.4 on Mac 10.6.8

```
{CurrentValue["FontMWidth"], CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]}
(* {12.9621, 9.875} *)
```

Mma 8.0.4 on Windows

```
{CurrentValue["FontMWidth"], CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]}
(* {12.6, 10} *)
```

In other words similar em widths and line heights. The upshot is that I have had problems creating a grid on a Mac that doesn't go offscale when viewed on Windows.

The screen resolutions (`SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]`) are 72 for Mac and 96 for Windows. The ratio of Windows image width for Mac width is close to 96/72 but the heights are not close to that ratio at all -- but in any case there is no mention of screen resolutions in the documentation.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what is happening here and how I can get a grid of the same size on both Mac and Windows?

**Edit**

I think this example by @SjoerdC.deVries nails it:

```
Grid[{{"MMMMMMMMMMM", "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM"}}, ItemSize -> 5,
 Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

If the item size is in ems then you should expect only 5 "M" characters to fit in a grid cell ...right?

Following the comment from @Silvia I have tested Serif, Sans-serif and monospace fonts:

Sans-serif -- Helvetica gives 4Ms

[image]

Serif -- Times gives 4Ms

[image]

Monospace -- Monaco gives many Ms

[image]

Note that using lower case "m" made no difference. Note that further investigation shows that the word wrapping has an effect here. With *just* 5Ms the item size almost works.

[image]

Initial summary: So either the documentation is wrong, or it is incomplete, or the implementation is broken.

Subsequent summary: the problem seems to reside with how Mathematica determines the font being used when doing the size calculations. It clearly responds when StandardForm is changed but does not respond to local font usage (apparently). Otherwise an item size of x/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"] should surely deliver an item xMs wide.

**Edit #2**

Confirmed as a bug by WRI tech support.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Yes: `Attributes[Grid] == {Sadistic || Bugged}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes very frustrating.

Comment: Do you really need it to be the exact same number of pixels or show the same amount of text? Since Windows uses more pixels to show text of the same point size, don't you actually want your grid to consume more pixels on Windows?

Comment: @Verbeia I make a notebook of a given size containing a grid of a given size. I looks a certain way on Mac but when opened in Windows is way way too big -- and i would prefer not to have scrollbars. I have both Mac and Windows computers but would prefer not to have to make a specific version (layout) for each. Presumably with pixels the screen resolution ratios between the platforms cannot account for some of the differences but not all. If an item size is a certain number of ems then surely we just need to know how many pixels to an em on each platform?? Ditto line heights.

Comment: Is Mathematica's definition of 'em' not the same as the [accepted definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)) (same as point size)?.

Comment: Seems version dependent. On my system, win7-64 I get {983, 274} on v8 and {863, 274} on v9. My screen is 120  dpi. Interestingly, if I put the seemingly useless (1 #;#)&@ before the first (of 4) `CurrentValue` in your code I get {804,254} and {707, 254}, respectively.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries is `CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]` also varying?

Comment: Indeed, it is 12.6 and 14.4 for v8 and v9, respectively.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries with this information are you able to derive -- perhaps by magic? -- how item sizes are determined :)

Comment: No idea how to approach this, but I'll be trying to gather some information that may be useful. For instance your line `{CurrentValue["FontMWidth"], CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]}` takes up 829 pixels in v8 and 948 in v9. Their ratio is precisely that of their respective em values. So,  it seems that the standard font differs between those versions.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries where I say in bold to stop reading if I am wrong ...am i wrong ...misunderstanding things? If an item size is in em units and you specify the size as x/(em) then shouldn't you get the same size in the layout (x) -- and by extension same grid size -- regardless of the size of the em?

Comment: `ItemSize` is a strange beast. Check the first example on the help page and count the item size there in terms of number of characters and see if you understand that. I don't. Could also try `Grid[{{"MMMMMMMMMM", "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM"}}, ItemSize -> 5]`.

Comment: As to your question: perhaps padding plays a role as well?

Comment: It would be nice if we could have 2D layouts that just work!

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries An interesting thing I found from your example is, if I set the `"StandardForm"` in the stylesheet to any (I guess) **serif font**, the output looks indeed 5 `M` width! But any **sans-serif font** would behave strange! [(A screen capture)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u9qTt.jpg)

Comment: @Silvia that is an interesting development in this mystery. thanks for this information.

Comment: You're welcome! I always use my own stylesheet, with a serif font `StandardForm`, otherwise there would be no chance for me to notice that:)

Comment: @Silvia I repeated this on my Mac. Note that your screen grab is actually 4Ms not 5. I randomly tested maybe 30 fonts and all (both serif and sans serif) bar the fixed width fonts Courier and Monaco produced 4Ms. To get 5Ms I had to make the item size 5.7!

Comment: It is indeed 5Ms in my screen grab. The 5th place is occupied by the `\[Continuation]` symbols. If there are no more than 5 Ms, they will be placed in the same row. (See [my screen grab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7uQzE.jpg) please.) And I agree with you that it's not about sans-serif or serif but something else, which makes it more confusing..

Comment: Another wrinkle, `FontMWidth` is exactly twice `FontNWidth` for all fonts I tested on my Mac. Surely this will all be ironed out when Mathematica [goes HiDPI](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30104/100).

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few things I have learnt trying to find work arounds -- they may or may not be useful to others. As I indicated in my final edit to the question Wolfram tech support have indicated that the behaviour is a bug.

**1: Test items size for "M" width**

The font family setting for `ItemStyle`has no effect on how the grid cell size is determined. It is solely controlled by `BaseStyle` but even then monospace fonts fail.

```
Grid[{{"MMMMM", "MMMMMMMMMM", "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM"}},
 Alignment -> {Left, Top},
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", 12],
 Frame -> All,
 ItemSize -> 5,
 Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**2: Consistent grid pixel widths across platforms**

A barrier is that `CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]` when entered as an `ItemSize` specification does not return the `CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]` of the font being used in the grid. So while something like

```
ItemSize->Dynamic@{100/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"],2}
```

might be expected to give the same pixel size per cell regardless of font it does not. A work around is to determine `CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]` for a given font separately. You could have a library with this information or you could do it dynamically.

This

```
img = Rasterize@
  Grid[{{"MMMMM", Dynamic@(m1 = CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]), 
     "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM"}},
   Alignment -> {Left, Top},
   BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", 12],
   Frame -> All,
   ItemSize -> Dynamic@(size/m1),
   Spacings -> {0, 0}]

ImageDimensions[img]
```

only works on a second and subsequent evaluation because the value of `m1` isn't available the first time around. The way around this is to use `Overlay`

```
Clear[m1];

img = Rasterize@Overlay[{
    Grid[{{Dynamic@(m1 = CurrentValue["FontMWidth"])}},
     Alignment -> {Left, Top},
     BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Courier", 12, White],
     Frame -> All,
     Spacings -> {0, 0}],
    Grid[{{"MMMMM", "MMMMM", "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM"}},
     Alignment -> {Left, Top},
     BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Courier", 12],
     Frame -> All,
     ItemSize -> Dynamic@(size/m1),
     Spacings -> {0, 0}]
    }]

ImageDimensions[img]
```

On my Mac (10.6.8 V8.0.4) this renders a grid width of 302 pixels for all fonts I tried except "Georgia" which gave 305 pixels. I then switched to Windows (V8.0.4) and got the same pixel width as well as the same exception (and width) for "Georgia".

Comment: Btw, I'm no longer trying to use `Grid` for anything more than a grid structure. For size control I'm always setting `Grid` `Spacings` to `{0,0}` and I map/wrap items with `Pane/Panel` or friends with specific size (ofc don't forget to set `ImageMargins->0`). Just a loose thoughts.