# How to set zoom and screen environment from GenerateDocument?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, document-creation

`GenerateDocument` does not have any options for settings on the notebook it creates. How do I generate a document with

`ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Printout", Magnification -> 1.5`

without clicking these options on the template notebook at design time.  That is, I could select these options when editing the template but I would prefer not to have to remember to set them every time I finish working on a template (and deselecting them every time I start working on a template).

The template file is not open when `GenerateDocument` is called. I am passing the full filename string of the template notebook to `GenerateDocument` along with the association of parameters as the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
nb = GenerateDocument["ExampleData/BasicTemplate.nb", <|"author" -> "Henry Jones"|>];

SetOptions[nb, {ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Printout", Magnification -> 1.5}]
```

Comment: Are you getting any odd zooming issues from this? When I do this the zoom is much bigger that 1.5 on the screen even though the zoom selector in the lower right says 150%.  I have to select another zoom level and then reselect 150% to get it to the correct magnification.  I have [high DPI scaling](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58119/blurred-frontend-text-in-mathematica-10-windows-high-dpi-display/80957#80957) disabled to stop the blurring.  Do you see this as well?

Comment: I haven't measured the resulting zoom (but it was clearly zoomed; I also used a zoom of 3 which was bigger still), but I recall that in my case the zoom selector was still on 100%, so it didn't seem to have been updated.

Comment: @Edmund The Magnification set by this method is the same as using the menu Window►Magnification. In some situations this is different to setting the magnification in the lower right corner. Make sure that the magnification in the notebook you use to execute this code has a magnification of 100%.