# Mathematica 12 compatibility with earlier versions under macOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: mac-os-x, compatibility

I currently run the following:

- Mathematica 10.3.0.0 on a
- Mac Pro (Late 2013)running
- macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6.

I want to upgrade the OS to macOS 10.15 Catalina.

To do so, I understand that I will need to upgrade to Mathematica 12 as Catalina will no longer support earlier versions of Mathematica.

Does any means or do any guidelines exist to evaluate compatibility of code developed in earlier versions of Mathematica with Mathematica 12 running on Catalina?

Note: I don't mind updating code, I just have things I need running over the next month or so.  If I do need to spend time updating code for the newer version, I need to plan when I will do that.

Also, given the contemplated OS update, I won't have the option of keeping an earlier version of Mathematica around to run what I'll need until I get everything updated for compatibility.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Mathematica 11 work with MacOS Catalina 10.15](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207522/does-mathematica-11-work-with-macos-catalina-10-15)

Comment: @BobHanlon -- While helpful to understand why the issues exist and there background, the original post and answers seem to focus on workarounds (e.g., Parallels) or the lack of them.  I hope to find a way to evaluate compatibility of notebooks written in the earlier version of Mma when run on Catalina.

Comment: Jagra, if you by the new version anyways, you can install it in parallel to the old version. Then you can test it on your own. My personal advice: Do not upgrade to Catalina if you do not have to. My system is super instable and laggy since then. (Admittedly, this could also be caused by a battery issue I had in summer; the battery has been replaced in the meantime, but maybe the logic board had been damaged.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does any means or do any guidelines exist to evaluate compatibility of code developed in earlier versions of Mathematica with Mathematica 12 running on Catalina?

The operating system (Catalina) should not matter. What matters is the changes between Mathematica versions 10.3 and 12.0.

Unfortunately, Wolfram does not publish a list of breaking changes between versions (as e.g. the MathWorks does for MATLAB). [They used to publish a limited set of incompatible changes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html), but the list stops at version 7.  If you care about this, perhaps you can contact Wolfram Support and suggest that they list breaking changes with each new version (I do care and I have requested it already, but I am only one person).

There is a QA on this site which lists some changes, but it is far from exhaustive:

- [Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 7?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56728/12)

The most realistic option is to test your code in version 12.0 before you commit to the upgrade. Perhaps the [Free Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) can be helpful in this testing (as well as a trial version of M12.0).

Comment: I will add my voice to the request for an updated list of breaking changes.