# Labeling a grid

Tags: grid-layouts, labeling, list-manipulation

I have

```
m = {{0, -1, -2, -3, -4}, {1, 0, -1, -2, -3}, {2, 1, 0, -1, -2}, {3, 
    2, 1, 0, -1}, {4, 3, 2, 1, 0}};
```

And a grid `Grid[m,Frame->All]`

I would like to label the grid such that every column has a number above it and every row has a number to its side. 
This is what I've currently managed to do.

```
Labeled[Grid[m,Frame->All],{Y:{1,5},X:{1,5}},{Left,Top}]
```

How can I label the grid appropriately?

Comment: I highly recomment [this answer by Mike Honeychurch](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21122/5478) but if you do not need such interface take a look at `Headings` option for `TableForm`. You can allways add such heading as a new column and row, then you have to read [adding columns/rows](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189/5478).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps what you want:

```
m = Array[Subtract, {5, 5}, 0];
r = Range @ 5;

Grid[
 ArrayFlatten[{{"", {r}}, {{r}\[Transpose], m}}],
 Frame -> All
]
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. +1 For simplicity.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `TableForm`, e.g.

```
col = CharacterRange["A", "E"];
row = CharacterRange["a", "e"];
TableForm[m, TableHeadings -> {row, col}]
```

A way using `Grid`:

```
Grid[{PadLeft[col, 6, ""]}~Join~
  MapThread[PadLeft[#1, 6, #2] &, {m, row}], 
 Dividers -> {{False, True, {False}}, {False, True, {False}}}]
```

[image]

[image]