# Print array with indices

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

Is there a single function that prints an array together with the indices?
I know how to achieve this with `Grid[{Range[n],array},Frame->All]`, but I vaguely
recall there is a special function that achieves this?
I am not finding it via searches...

---

[image: Array]

---

Comment: Related (probably not a dupe because no explicit numbering is requested): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47164/131. Fancy: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21122/131

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html) does the trick:

```
array = {{"a", "b", "c", "d"}};

TableForm[array, TableHeadings -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

More flexible would be a [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html)-based solution:

```
Grid[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, array[[1]]] // Transpose, 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ah, I found `TableForm`, but did not see the `TableHeadings` modifier. Thanks!