# Row and Column Headings for a Grid

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts

It would be useful for me if I could write:

```
Grid[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, 
 GridHeadings -> {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}}]
```

just like

```
TableForm[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}}]
```

except that I don't want the two lines `TableForm` produces.

How could I add this additional option to `Grid`?

Comment: I think it is a duplicate but I can't find it. Meanwhile I'm linking [great answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21117/5478) by Mike Honeychurch.

Comment: It is worth to mention that `TableForm` is based on `GridBox` and we can see the "definition" of `TableForm` by evaluating: `FormatValues[TableForm]`.

Comment: IMHO, it's probably best practice not to override the built-in functions if it's not necessary.

Comment: @Kuba - thanks for the very nice link

Comment: this is 3 years old but may be of interest: http://ibnhconsulting.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/styling-tables-in-mathematica.html

Comment: @Mike - Great link ! I am already working with "tables.nb"-features.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you wish to convert the answers below to emulate the Option syntax you requested please see:  [Functions with Options](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/358)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
head = {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}};


Join[Transpose[{Join[{""}, head[[1]]]}], Join[head[[{2}]], data], 2] // Grid
```

> [image]

Comment: I am very pleased. "MyGrid[d_, h_] := 
 Join[Transpose[{Join[{""}, h[[1]]]}], Join[h[[2]], d], 2] // Grid" now easily gives me what I wanted. Just flipped an acceptance coin between rasher and you.

Comment: @eldo: In the future, please use *Mathematica*'s `RandomInteger` for such decisions: I've seen coins with *Kuba*'s face on both sides... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of options that would do this to `Grid`. Grid is really just matrix with extra options build-in.

Can you just build-it in manually?

```
fillInHeader[h_, data_] := Module[{n, grid},
   n = Length[data];
   grid = Table[Null, {n + 1}, {n}];
   grid[[2 ;; -1, All]] = h[[1]];
   grid[[1, 2 ;; -1]] = h[[2]];
   grid[[2 ;; -1, 2 ;; -1]] = data;
   grid
   ];
headings = {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}};
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
Grid[fillInHeader[headings, data]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to add other Grid options, you can now do this

```
Grid[fillInHeader[headings, data], Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use it with `GraphicsGrid` also

```
 GraphicsGrid[fillInHeader[headings, data], ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

etc...

Comment: using your code above: why shouldn't it be posssible to unprotect "Grid" and add it as an option?

Comment: @eldo, I would not know how to do this. I also think making a simple function to fill-in the headers on the sides of the data is just simpler than what you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
headings = {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}};

Grid[Prepend[Flatten /@ Transpose[{headings[[1]], data}], 
             PadLeft[headings[[2]], Length@data[[1]] + 1, ""]]]
```

[image]

I assume data sublists of same length, if not the case, more work needed as this (and other answers so far) will give goofy results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea that makes use of ArrayFlatten

```
 GridPlus[data_, headers_, opts : OptionsPattern[Grid]] := 
 Grid[ArrayFlatten[{{{{""}}, {headers[[1]]}}, \
 {Transpose[{headers[[2]]}], data}}], opts]
```