# Rotated Row and Normal Column Headings for a Grid

Tags: graphics

I'd like to add a label to the top of each column of a `GraphicsGrid` and to the Left of each Row.

[This prior question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48992/row-and-column-headings-for-a-grid) does not seem to allow rotating the row label.

The `Row` labels need to be rotated, so the `TableForm` does not suffice, anyway I also need these to be graphics objects for exporting.

Given is the example output generated below, where the `GraphicsGrid` is what I am working with:

```
pl = Table[ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 60]], {4}, {6}];

(*Nearly but not rotated*)
TableForm[pl, TableHeadings -> {{"r1 rotated", "r2 rotated", "r3 rotated", "r4 rotated"}, {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6"}}]

(* Ideal if labels added to this *)
GraphicsGrid[pl]
```

Appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: why not `TableHeadings -> {Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ {"r1 rotated", 
    "r2 rotated", "r3 rotated", "r4 rotated"}, {"c1", "c2", "c3", 
   "c4", "c5", "c6"}}`?

Comment: That did the trick.  If you want to post the comment as an answer I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll answer with your suggestion if you don't object?

Comment: Hedgehog, posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pl = Table[ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 60]], {3}, {4}];
TableForm[pl, TableHeadings -> 
   {Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ {"r1 rotated", "r2 rotated", "r3 rotated", "r4 rotated"}, 
   {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6"}},
  TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image]