# What are the UnitConvert units for ItemSize and FieldSize?

Tags: units, printing, size

I have discovered the unit for `ImageSize` is `"DesktopPublishingPoints"` as setting

```
ImageSize -> {
 QuantityMagnitude@ UnitConvert[Quantity[10, "Centimeters"], "DesktopPublishingPoints"], 
 Automatic}
```

produces an image that is 10cm wide.  This agrees with the toolbar ruler and printing.

However, the same conversion does not work with either `ItemSize` nor `FieldSize`.  The results are too wide (confirmed by toolbar ruler) but they are of equal width which indicates they are of the same unit.

What `UnitConvert` unit should be use for `ItemSize` and `FieldSize` options to produce output of a specified size?

Mma 11.0.1 on Win 7 Pro

---

This produces a `Panel` that is 10cm wide by toolbar ruler and when printed.

```
Panel["Select something", Background -> LightBlue, 
 ImageSize -> {
  QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[10, "Centimeters"], "DesktopPublishingPoints"], 
  Automatic}]
```

These produce outputs that are much too wide.

```
Grid[{{Null}}, 
 ItemSize -> 
  QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[10, "Centimeters"],"DesktopPublishingPoints"],
  Background -> LightBlue]

InputField[Null, 
 FieldSize -> 
  QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[10, "Centimeters"],"DesktopPublishingPoints"],
  Background -> LightBlue]
```

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109813) [And another one.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17795)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UnitConvert` will not be of much help to you, since `ItemSize` and `FieldSize` are dependent on the metrics of the current font.

> The width for FieldSize is measured in ems; the height in line heights.

You will have to do the work yourself, using `CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]` and `CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]`.

Comment: here is a curious thing ... `UnitConvert[Quantity[1., "ems"], "DesktopPublishingPoints"]  (*1. pt*)`

Comment: I think `ItemSize->QuantityMagnitude@ UnitConvert[Quantity[10, "Centimeters"], "DesktopPublishingPoints"] / CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]`does the trick.

Comment: @ihojnicki `FieldSize` does not fully cooperate with the above but it is very close.  Any idea why it is a little wider for `FieldSize` but exact for `ItemSize`?

Comment: Best guess without looking at the code...  The `InputField` is using a different font.  So you would have to spec it using `Dynamic` or `RuleDelayed`.

Comment: a bit aside but note the "em" width is not literally the width of the capital "M".. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography). Learned something new today..

Comment: Wrapping the right-hand side of `FieldSize` in `Dynamic` actually makes it worse. It becomes huge. `InputField["FontMWidth", 
 FieldSize -> 
  Dynamic[QuantityMagnitude@
     UnitConvert[Quantity[10, "Centimeters"], 
      "DesktopPublishingPoints"]/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]], 
 Background -> LightBlue]`